# Quarkus not validate DTO with hibernate-validator

Tags: kotlin, validation, quarkus, hibernate-validator

I have an endpoint based on Quarkus:

```
import com.company.report.dto.ReportDto
import com.company.report.service.ReportService
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import javax.validation.Valid

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes
import javax.ws.rs.POST
import javax.ws.rs.Path
import javax.ws.rs.Produces
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response

@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/app")
class ReportController(
    private val reportService: ReportService
) {

    @POST
    @Path("/report")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces("application/pdf")
    fun generateReport(@Valid reportDto: ReportDto): Response {
        return Response
            .ok(reportService.generatePdfReport(reportDto), "application/pdf")
            .header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"Report.pdf\"")
            .build()
    }
}


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class ReportDto(
    @JsonProperty("rows") @NotNull val rows: List<ReportRowDto>
)


import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class ReportRowDto (
    @JsonProperty("name") @NotBlank(message = "name cant be blank") @NotNull(message = "name cant be null") val name: String
)

@Provider
class ValidationExceptionMapper : ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {
    override fun toResponse(exception: ConstraintViolationException): Response {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
            .entity("Validation failed: ${exception.message}")
            .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
            .build()
    }
}

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And `javax.annotation` is defined in parent pom and I can't change anything in there.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If the `name` is `null` or empty I expect `400` and the message about the error.
`"name cant be blank"` or `"name cant be blank"`accordingly annotation `message` parameter.

But instead of an error message in Postmen I've got `400` and `Failed to load PDF file.` and `The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax.`

Why did it happen, and how to fix it?

ps. Yes, I know it should work with storage, and return the download link but in my case, I need to return the document in the body.

Answer (score 1):

First, which version of Quarkus are you using? Because if you are using Quarkus 3+, you need to use `jakarta.validation`, not `javax.validation`.
Quarkus 3 is based on Jakarta EE 10 with the jakarta namespace.
`javax.validation` constraints will be completely ignored in Quarkus 3.

Then you miss a `@Valid` there:

```kotlin
@JsonProperty("rows") @NotNull val rows: List<ReportRowDto>
```

Comment: Yes, `@Valid` for `rows` and one more mistake for Kotlin specifically, we can't use a constructor for annotated fields, it should be var mutable varible.